# How can I get the first 50% of all posts (within a custom post type)?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm trying to make a multi column layout. Seen as CSS3 adoption of column layouts is still thin on the ground, I was thinking maybe I could grab the first half of all my posts (and then the second), and add them in their own UL elements.

I'm not sure how / if this is possible with a Wp_Query?

I want to end up with my posts in alphabetical order, but split into two lists (using two queries, I guess), thus:

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
.
.
.
</li>m</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>n</li>
.
.
.
</li>z</li>
</ul>
```

I could then style each list with CSS and get a layout kind of like a multi column layout in CSS3.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to structure my queries here?

***edit to explain how this isn't a duplicate***

It's about forming a two column layout *sure*, but the question is very different: 'how to get half of all posts', not how to solve a very specific layout use case as is the linked 'duplicate'. (which I didn't find on account of it not being the same question).

Further, I was looking for posts sorted alphabetically, vertically descending, not A|B, C|D as in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split it into two lists, you could use [`wp_count_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) to count the number of your published posts

```
$total_cpt = wp_count_posts('cpt')->publish;
```

divide it by 2:

```
$half_of_cpt = sprintf( '%d', $total_cpt / 2 );
```

and then you could use this number in the loop to split your list.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thanks @birgire! (just incase anyone else is wondering: you can use the 'offset' property for the second query to start where the first list leaves off).

Comment: great ;-)  ps: one could also use `$my_query->current_post` to get the current post position inside the while loop and compare it to `$half_of_cpt` , one just have to remember that is starts from `0`.

Comment: @josh For me this is not the right solution. In wordpress there are infinite possibilities of cpt archive queries: tax query, meta query, query with pagination, any combination of them, and so on. This code works only for one single query: `new WP_Query('post_type=cpt&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1');` with any query different from this, answer code will fail for the scope. For test, try to add pagination...

Answer (score 4):

The following

- will work for every query (even with pagination), so it's more flexible
- need only one loop (as the best implementation of `wp_count_posts`)
- don't call other additional db query like `wp_count_posts` do, so it's faster
- do not need any other variable ouside loop, so it's simpler

  ```
  $args = array('post_type'=>'cpt', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC'); // any args here
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
      if ( ( $query->current_post + 1 ) == ceil($query->post_count / 2) ) echo '</ul><ul>';

    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
  endif;
  ```

Comment: Much more elegant solution :)

Comment: beautiful solution and exactly what I need!